# Proving $\pi(\frac1A+\frac1B+\frac1C)\ge(\sin\frac A2+\sin\frac B2+\sin\frac C2)(\frac 1{\sin\frac A2}+\frac 1{\sin\frac B2}+\frac 1{\sin\frac C2})$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

> Let $\Delta ABC$, prove that
> $$\pi\left(\dfrac{1}{A}+\dfrac{1}{B}+\dfrac{1}{C}\right)\ge \left(\sin{\dfrac{A}{2}}+\sin{\dfrac{B}{2}}+\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}} \right) \left(\dfrac{1}{\sin{\dfrac{A}{2}}}+\dfrac{1}{\sin{\dfrac{B}{2}}}+\dfrac{1}{\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}}}\right)$$

Comment: When does the equality hold?! Is it not $3$ instead of $\pi$.? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Inceptio It holds for $A=B=C=\pi/3$

Comment: @AméricoTavares: I think I cracked it. Have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x = A/2, y = B/2, z = C/2$.

The desired inequality is written as
$$(x + y + z)(1/x + 1/y + 1/z) \ge (\sin x + \sin y + \sin z)\left(\frac{1}{\sin x} + \frac{1}{\sin y} + \frac{1}{\sin z}\right)$$
or
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x} - \frac{\sin x}{\sin y} - \frac{\sin y}{\sin x}\right) \ge 0$$
or
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{1}{\sin x\, \sin y}
(y\sin y - x\sin x)\left(\frac{\sin x}{x} - \frac{\sin y}{y}\right) \ge 0. \tag{1}$$

Let $f(u) := \frac{\sin u}{u}$ and $g(u) := u\sin u$.
We have $f'(u) = \frac{\cos u (u - \tan u)}{u^2}$
and $g'(u) = \sin u + u\cos u$.
Thus, $f'(u) < 0$ on $(0, \pi/2]$,
and $g'(u) > 0$ on $(0, \pi/2]$.
Thus, we have, for all $x, y\in (0, \pi/2]$
$$(y\sin y - x\sin x)\left(\frac{\sin x}{x} - \frac{\sin y}{y}\right) \ge 0.$$
Thus, (1) is true.

We are done.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you,

$$\sin \dfrac{A}{2} \sin \dfrac{B}{2} \sin \dfrac{C}{2} \le \dfrac {1}{8}$$(With **equality** iff $A=B=C$)

Well here's a proof of it:

We have

$$\sin \dfrac{A}{2} \sin \dfrac{B}{2} \sin \dfrac{C}{2}$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{2}[\cos \dfrac{A-B}{2}-\cos \dfrac {A+B}{2}]\sin \dfrac{C}{2}$$

$$\le \dfrac{1}{2}[1-\sin \dfrac{C}{2}]\sin \dfrac{C}{2}$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{2}[\sin \dfrac{C}{2}-\sin^2 \dfrac{C}{2}]$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{2}[ \dfrac{1}{4} -(\dfrac{1}{2}- \sin \dfrac{C}{2})^2] \le \dfrac{1}{8}$$

$$A+B+C= \pi$$

Maximum value$(ABC)=\dfrac{\pi^3}{27}$(From **AM-GM** inequality)

Maximum value of $(AB+BC+CA) =\dfrac{\pi^2}{9}$

$$\dfrac{1}{A}+\dfrac{1}{B}+\dfrac{1}{C}=\dfrac{AB+BC+CA}{ABC}$$

We have 
$$\dfrac{1}{ABC} \ge \dfrac{27}{\pi^3}$$

$$(AB+BC+CA) \ge \dfrac{\pi^2}{3}$$

(You can multiply inequalities, when they are both positive)

We get, $$\dfrac{1}{A}+\dfrac{1}{B}+\dfrac{1}{C} \ge \dfrac{\pi^2}{3}.\dfrac{27}{\pi^3}$$

$$\dfrac{1}{A}+\dfrac{1}{B}+\dfrac{1}{C}\ge 9 \dfrac{1}{\pi}$$

(Multiplying $\pi$)

$$ \pi. (\dfrac{1}{A}+\dfrac{1}{B}+\dfrac{1}{C}) \ge 9$$

You can carry on from here. (Manipulation of inequalities, nothing much.)

Comment: I suppose you mean minimum value of $AB+AC+BC$? Typo: $\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}+\frac{1}{C}=\frac{AB+AC+BC}{ABC}$ and not $\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{C}+\frac{1}{C}=\frac{AB+AC+BC}{ABC}$. Also, where did you get $\frac{\pi^2}{9}$ as an extremal value of $AB+AC+BC$? That value doesn't seem right. Also the R.H.S can equal $9$, when $A=B=C=\frac{\pi}{3}$, so something is wrong.

Comment: Well, it has to be $\frac {3 \pi^2}{9}$. And I got it from **AM-GM**. (Didn't take $3$ which was in the denominator to the other side)

Comment: Doesn't A.M.-G.M. give $AB+AC+BC \geq 3\sqrt[3]{A^2B^2C^2}$? You can't conclude anything about the minimal value of $AB+AC+BC$ from there since $ABC \leq \frac{\pi^3}{27}$.

Comment: Maximum value of $ABC$ is $\dfrac{\pi^3}{27}$.? I took the maximum value of it. $AB+AC+BC \geq 3\sqrt[3]{A^2B^2C^2}$, And $\dfrac{\pi^3}{27} \ge ABC$

Comment: Those 2 inequalities are true, but you can't combine them to get a minimal value of $AB+AC+BC$. If we try $A=B=\frac{\pi}{4}, C=\frac{\pi}{2}$, then $AB+AC+BC=\frac{5\pi^2}{16}<\frac{\pi^2}{3}$

Comment: No. No! I took the maximum value of it($AC+BC+AB$). Have a look.:)

Comment: @IvanLoh: Still got some errors in it? I can not take the minimum value of it, now I'm aware. Thanks. Do inform if it has still got some errors.:)